# Convert base64 string from the browser to the standard used in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, base64

How do I convert from a base64 string used in the web browser to a base64 string used in Objective-C?

I noticed that the base64 used in Objective-C is not the same base64 standard used in the browser. I try to submit a base64 string from a UIWebView to Objective-C using a native bridge and post it using multipart/form-data. Though parsing the base64 string is not possible.

I use the following code for parsing:

```
NSData* value = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:_base64 options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```

I noticed that the Objective-C standard uses `\r\n` in every 64th character. And I try to insert this white-space character too.

```
NSString* base64 = [@"" stringByAppendingString:fields[key][@"value"]];
        NSMutableString* base64Buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i=0; i<base64.length; i++) {
            [base64Buffer appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C", [base64 characterAtIndex:i]]];
            if (i % 63 == 0) {
                [base64Buffer appendString:@"\r\n"];
            }
        }
```

Not any luck so far. There is at least 10 stackoverflow questions about this. But I have recently came down to the conclusion that Objective-C requires another standard of base64. Though reading Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 didn't help so much.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Base-64 used in the browser" or "Base-64 used in Objective-C". Base-64 is a language and environment independent data encoding format. Thus, your question does not make sense. If you fail to send data from your program, then the error is either in the data or in your program.

Comment: Furthermore: "I noticed that the Objective-C standard uses \r\n in every 64th character." - uhm, as mentioned above, there's not quite an "Objective-C standard". You may find different **libraries,** which may or may not produce output in different format. If you don't like the format of the encoder you are currently using, then change to another one.